# Heroku django no such app

Tags: python, django, git, heroku

I have followed the django getting started guide, word for word and I am presented with this `Heroku | No app` page.

[image]

Using the commands `foreman start` or `python manage.py runserver` work fine and I am able to view the app locally. It even seems fine when I `push` here is the result of `git push heroku`

```
Counting objects: 9, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5/5), 685 bytes, done.
Total 5 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0)
-----> Python app detected
-----> No runtime.txt provided; assuming python-2.7.4.
-----> Using Python runtime (python-2.7.4)
-----> Installing dependencies using Pip (1.3.1)
       Cleaning up...
-----> Collecting static files
       266 static files copied.

-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> web

-----> Compiled slug size: 139.4MB
-----> Launching... done, v18
       http://spritesheet-gen.herokuapp.com deployed to Heroku
```

Here is the last response from `heroku logs`. Which also seems fine?

```
2013-11-25T16:43:21+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2013-11-25T16:43:58.322717+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy ed36962 by dalberto.adler@gmail.com
2013-11-25T16:43:58.369387+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v18 created by dalberto.adler@gmail.com
2013-11-25T16:43:58+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2013-11-25T16:43:59.550336+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-11-25T16:44:27.656355+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn spritesheetgen.wsgi`
2013-11-25T16:44:28.625250+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-11-25 16:44:28 [2] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:57632 (2)
2013-11-25T16:44:28.625326+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-11-25 16:44:28 [2] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2013-11-25T16:44:28.632096+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-11-25 16:44:28 [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
2013-11-25T16:44:28.624290+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-11-25 16:44:28 [2] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 18.0
2013-11-25T16:44:28.940383+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
```

My `Procfile` looks like this

```
web: gunicorn spritesheetgen.wsgi
```

My project structure looks something like this (click for source)

- Procfile
- [manage.py](http://pastebin.com/1Z0H2wdj#)
- [requirements.txt](http://pastebin.com/ZkpBxahV)
- spritesheetgen/

  - [wsgi.py](http://pastebin.com/aB35cKqp)
  - [settings.py](http://pastebin.com/sWGMEWdr)
  - [urls.py](http://pastebin.com/g4f8um4t#)

I also tried doing `heroku run foreman start` but

I have done a fair bit of googling and not found any solutions i guess I am missing something simple but fundamental. Any pointers appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out it was not my fault but Heroku's fault. Some kind of DNS misrouting problem, which after contacting them they fixed for me.

**Conclusion** if you can run `foreman start` to run a local server and heroku doesn't complain when you do `git push heroku` then its probably not your fault and you should contact them via the Support tab on their website.