# Minimal working heroku django app

Tags: python, django, git, heroku

I have been having some problems with deploying my django app to heroku. I have triple checked the getting started guide several times and I am getting quite frustrated. The most annoying thing is that I don't get any errors during deployment, in `heroku logs` or during local deployment. Here is an [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20198969/heroku-django-no-such-app) with more details.

The easiest solution at this stage would probably be to reverse engineer a minimal working django app which I could push straight to my heroku repo without any extra config.

(The smaller the app the better a simple `<h1>hello world</h1>` would do but it would need to include `venv`, `requirements.txt` and of course `Procfile`)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take your pick. Either of these should work for you.

- https://github.com/auzigog/django-template-heroku
- https://github.com/cyberdelia/django-heroku-template

Comment: @david_adler, any reason you unaccepted my answer? Are these not what you were looking for?

Comment: Hi Thomas ideally the repo should contain a venv directory as suggested by the [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django)

Comment: @david_adler they'll never include a venv directory, because that is created at slug generation time. You never ever *ever* keep your virtual environment in version control, only the requirements.txt required to create it. On you're local development environment, you run `virtualenv venv --distribute` as stated in the docs you linked me to. When you deploy, Heroku will also run this command as part of python buildpack execution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try http://django.ironcoder.me - visual composer, which deploys working Django app to your heroku account.